# CKEditor TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'c.langEntries')

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have added a CKEditor ver 4.1 to my project ( NSBasic ) and am using it with datatables editor.

If I download any of the 3 CDEditor standard packages ( Basic - Standard or Full https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/ ) it all works okay.

However if I create a custom package I get the following error :

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'c.langEntries')
```

It flags here

```
 CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang = function(a, d, b) {
    var c = this.get(a);
    a = c.langEntries || (c.langEntries = {}); //error here null is not an object (evaluating 'c.langEntries')
    c = c.lang || (c.lang = []);
    c.split && (c = c.split(","));
    -1 == CKEDITOR.tools.indexOf(c, d) && c.push(d);
    a[d] = b
};
```

The path to the CKEditor os here:

```
<script src="http://www.aceoftoons.com/ckeditorCustom3/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Any ideas how I can trace the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using a third-party plugin with language files configured incorrectly. I remember I once had such a problem with `selectallcontextmenu` plugin. I would recommend that you first start with plugins only created by CKSource (each plugin has its own website where you can check its author) and when it works start adding custom plugins one by one.

Third-party plugins are usually ok, but there are some which don't work as intended thus you need to be careful. Fortunately you can easily verify the plugin by looking at its compatibility table (it should support latest version released) and user comments. If there is anything wrong they will let the author know about it. If the author cares about this plugin he will fix this problem. If he does not he will leave it as it is. In such cases I recommend down voting such plugin so that other user could know.